# Docker hub vs docker cloud

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-cloud

I have a small confusion between docker hub and docker cloud. I have docker images that I need to be installed in the client server and run the containers. I believe this can be done using docker hub which allows to push and pull docker images in my private repository. So what is the use of docker cloud? Is it to store the images in my own aws account rather than storing it in docker hub? The container needs to be installed in the client server, so what do I need to use, docker hub or docker cloud?

Comment: They are now integrated, along with Docker Store, in a new updated version of Docker Hub. [Here is what they posted in their blog](https://blog.docker.com/2018/12/the-new-docker-hub/) on December 13 2018.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For your needs, you should probably go with Docker Hub.

The Docker Cloud has more added [features](https://cloud.docker.com/swarm/clodal/dashboard/onboarding/cloud-registry) and so it is more extensive than Docker Hub. It seems like Docker Cloud is built on top of Docker Hub to provide a more comprehensive solution in the Docker eco-system.

However, when it comes to the core feature of fetching/storing images to and from your Docker repository, it's still primarily powered by Docker Hub considering this statement from the Docker Cloud docs:

> Docker Cloud uses Docker Hub as its native registry for storing both
>   public and private repositories. Once you push your images to Docker
>   Hub, they will be available in Docker Cloud.

Additional reading:

- [Overview of Docker Cloud](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/)
- [Overview of Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/)

Comment: so in other words, dockerhub is like github and dockercloud is jenkins?